# turn on nearby friend in android

Tags: facebook

Facebook told me that I must follow these steps to enable Nearby friend:

```
To turn Nearby Friends on or off on an iPhone or Android:
Tap More
Tap Nearby Friends
Tap Setting
Tap to turn Nearby Friends on or off
```

I'm using Facebook latest on Android with Samsung Core Prime and I can not do those steps cause of I dont see Nearby Friend on the screen,
Please help me for enable it!
Many thanks!
I can not screenshot the phone, but I swear I can not see the the "nearby firends" button at all. 
samsung told me do these steps, but it's totally no help!

> To capture a screenshot, press and hold the Home Home key and the
>   Power/Lock key simultaneously until a white border flashes around the
>   edges of the screen. The screenshot will be copied to the clipboard
>   and saved to the Screenshots folder in the Gallery.

Answer (score 1):

[Those are the correct instructions](https://www.facebook.com/help/712863802098411).  However, Nearby Friends was launched last April as a gradual roll-out.  As far as I can tell, it's still not generally available to everyone.  I do not have the option myself.

Comment: You are probably right. I've got the latest version and I cannot see the Nearby Friends option.